# Why Does I Cannot Call onReceive() in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver

I made a project in Android Studio, when I call someone to show a log, But it doesn't work.
**BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.callphone.call;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by 鱼呀鱼呀鱼籽酱 on 2016/4/23.
 */
public class OnCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "OnCallReceiver" ;

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "aaa");

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.callphone.call">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.callphone.call.OnCallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I cannot see the log on logcat when I calling a number.

But I type the same code in Eclipse , and it works.
there is code in Eclipse :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.callphone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.callphone.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.callphone.callPhoneReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**callPhoneReceiver**

```
package com.example.callphone;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class callPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("aaa");

    }

}
```

And in Eclipse with this code is works.
Why?
I am a chinese. My English is poor, Hope you can understand what I said....QAQ

Comment: I think it is working check your logs

Comment: no, I check it so much times,..